# Determine if MoveFileWithProgress was successful

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I used to get correct Win32Exception but now it is strange

```
Win32Exception ex1 = new Win32Exception();   
MoveFileWithProgress(oldFile, newFile, new CopyProgressRoutine(this.CopyProgressHandler), IntPtr.Zero, MoveFileFlags.MOVE_FILE_REPLACE_EXISTSING | MoveFileFlags.MOVE_FILE_WRITE_THROUGH | MoveFileFlags.MOVE_FILE_COPY_ALLOWED);
Win32Exception ex2 = new Win32Exception();
```

Getting

ex1: The system cannot find the file specified

ex2: the system could
not find the environment option that was entered

even though file is there and operation is successful.

---

*Additional information:*

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool MoveFileWithProgress(string lpExistingFileName,
       string lpNewFileName, CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine,
       IntPtr lpData, MoveFileFlags dwFlags);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return value of the call to `MoveFileWithProgress`. Only if it returns `false` did the function fail.

You must only call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` or create a new `Win32Exception` if the function failed. Like this:

```
if (!MoveFileWithProgress(...))
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

If you ask for the last error after a function call that succeeded you can get an error code that applies to an earlier function call that did fail. Basically, the last error code is ill-defined in the case where the API call succeeds. The documentation takes great care only to tell you to call `GetLastError` in case of failure.

This same principle applies to most Win32 functions but there are sometimes exceptions to this standard pattern. For instance, the registry functions return Win32 error codes directly. Always read the documentation carefully.